# how to check which one of result from mysql is online to redirect

Tags: php, mysql

how to check which one is working to redirect to it

mysql result is about 5 rows

my code is

```
$geturl = mysql_query("select * from urls ORDER BY timestamp DESC");
while($showurl = mysql_fetch_array($geturl)) {
$url = $showurl['url'];
$type = $showurl['urltype'];
   if ($type == 'x1' AND @fopen($url, 'r')) {
   header('Location: '.$url);
   die();
   fclose();
} elseif ($type == 'x2' AND @fopen($url, 'r')) {
header('Location: '.$url);
   die();
   fclose();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817046/get-the-site-status-up-or-down) Out, I guess simply addíng the solution provided there you'll be able to reach your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Well if one is online, it should respond to requests. So send both a request, and whichever one responds first (which will mean it is the online one) then select that one to redirect to. In PHP this probably can be done, but when using requests I usually go to Javascript and Ajax. I would do it like this:

```
var url1 = <?php echo $url1; ?> ;
var url2 = <?php echo $url2; ?> ;

$.get(url1, {}, function (data) {
window.location = url1;
});

$.get(url2, {}, function (data) {
window.location = url2;
});
```