# PHP - How to check if your sites is up (up to 15 sites)

Tags: php, web

I want to make script that check all my web sites if they are up or not.
The code works fine for one site, but when I try to check for e.g. 10 sites at once, code stop working.

```
<?php
    function checkStatus($url){
     $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; pt-pt) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27";
     $ch=curl_init();
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
     curl_exec($ch);
     $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
     curl_close($ch);
     if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300)
         return true;
     else
        return false;
    }
    $do = array();
    $n = 0;

    $myfile = fopen("domens.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        while(!feof($myfile)) {
            $do = fgets($myfile);
            $n = $n + 1;
        }
    fclose($myfile);
    echo '<br><br>';
    $trimmed = file('domens.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    for($x=0;$x<$n;$x++){
        if(checkStatus($trimmed[$x]))
            echo " <br>Website is up  " . $trimmed[$x];
        else
            echo "  <br> Website is down ". $trimmed[$x];
    }
?>
```

Comment: check this http://papermashup.com/php-check-if-your-website-is-up/

Comment: Could you reformat your code, please? Can't tell what's going on there..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the site status - up or down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817046/get-the-site-status-up-or-down)

Answer (score 0):

To check if your webserver is still working correctly, try a monitoring server like Nagios or Icinga.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkOnline($domain) {
   $curlInit = curl_init($domain);
   curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
   curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
   curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
   curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

   //get answer
   $response = curl_exec($curlInit);

   curl_close($curlInit);
   if ($response) return true;
   return false;
}

if(checkOnline('http://google.com')) { echo "google online\n"; }
if(checkOnline('http://facebook.com')) { echo "facebook online\n"; }
if(checkOnline('http://stackoverflow.com')) { echo "stackoverflow online\n"; }
```

Code from [Get the site status - up or down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817046/get-the-site-status-up-or-down)