# How to Check If the System is Down in Laravel

Tags: php

I want to check if the systems is Down

```
<?php
   ini_set("default_socket_timeout","05");
   set_time_limit(5);
   $f=fopen("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask","r");
   $r=fread($f,1000);
   fclose($f);
   if(strlen($r)>1) {
   echo("<span class='online'>Up</span>");
   }
   else {
   echo("<span class='offline'>Down</span>");
   }
?>
```

The code above only show if the url is available I want also to show Down if the system is provide this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)' in

Comment: the error message is pretty obvious... you can't connect to your DB

Comment: The question and the shown error are unrelated. There is no database code in your code fragment.

Comment: yes I understand the error what I want to get the message system is down due to above code say system is Up if I put the system that has error

Answer (score 0):

First get url contents, then check error exists on the contents or not:

```
$content = file_get_contents("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask");

if (strpos($content, 'Fatal error') !== false) {
    echo("<span class='offline'>Down</span>");
}
```

Comment: what if I want to check more than one url?

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered in StackOverflow before:

Using sockets:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9817077/1264260

Using Curl: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9817116/1264260

By the way, the error you are mentioning is not related to the question. Your db details are wrong.